# How can I stop on sortstart using jQuery UI sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable and don't want the LI to drag if there is a form inside. Attempting to cancel on sortstart with stopPropagation, returning false, or using the cancel method will make UI errors on drag. Any ideas to work around?

http://jsfiddle.net/davestein/WwDuU/

Comment: Submitted this: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8432 hopefully it's not a dupe that I missed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gonna say there is no answer just because it seems to be a bug and couldn't get any workarounds:
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8432

Answer (score 0):

I think it should include this to stop the sorting:

ui.draggable('cancel')

Comment: draggable is not a property on sortstart, nor does the helper or item have the data for draggable

Answer (score 0):

```
$(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
```

Comment: That doesn't do anything at all. Just blind fires. Tried in fiddle.